# Disabling a text field for a particular selection in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jsp

My application includes a textField and a dropdown box. When i select "All Campaigns" i should have my textfield disabled and it should remain enabled when i select "This Campaign".The code is given below for reference but i m not getting any errors or exceptions.Plese help me.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TextBoxDisabling</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findselected() {
        document.getElementById('selmenu');
        document.getElementById('txtField');
        (state.value == "All Campaign") ? txtField.disabled = true
                : txtField.disabled = false
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" name="form1">
<select name="selmenu"
    onChange="findselected()">
    <option value="1">This Campaign</option>
    <option value="2">All Campaign</option>
</select> <input type="text" size="20" id="txtField" name="txtField"></form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findselected() {
    var selMenu = document.getElementById('selmenu');
    var txtField = document.getElementById('txtField');
    if(selMenu.value == '2') 
        txtField.disabled = true
    else
        txtField.disabled = false
}

</script>


<form action="" method="POST" name="form1">
   <select name="selmenu" id="selmenu" onChange="findselected()">
    <option value="1">This Campaign</option>
        <option value="2">All Campaign</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="txtField" name="txtField">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For start.. your select is missing

```
id="selmenu"
```

And I also think, that your code

```
(state.value == "All Campaign")
```

Should be

```
(state.value == 2)
```

Because you are referencing value, not text.

Comment: + As Tom Glenn mentioned... you are not assigning elements to any variables. Which I didn't notice at first :)

Answer (score 0):

Your not assigning the values of your document.getElementById() calls to anything.

Try this:

```
function findselected() {
        var selMenu = document.getElementById('selmenu');
        var txtField = document.getElementById('txtField');
        if(selMenu.value == 2) ? txtField.disabled = true
                : txtField.disabled = false
}
```

Edit: Also, as previously suggested you need to give your select menu an ID of "selmenu".

Answer (score 0):

here is something that you need to do..

give your select element an id

```
<select name="selmenu"   id='selMenu'  onChange="findselected()">
```

and use this function:

```
function findselected() {    

  var state =   document.getElementById('selmenu');  
var txt =    document.getElementById('txtField');  
stateName = state.options[state.value-1].innerHTML;
(stateName == "All Campaign") ? txt.disabled = true : txt.disabled = false  ;

        }
```

Note that the value of selection is 1 or 2 and not the text in option. For selecting the text in option you will have to read the innerHTML of the element of options array.